# MySQL - Advice linking Multiple Tables - Is this right?

Tags: mysql, database, entity-relationship, join

Would someone mind advising me please regarding this table setup.

Its the first time designing a database.  This will be a part of it.

Its a report writing application.  Multiple Engineers can be assigned to attend any job/report and multiple engineers can author the report as well as attending.

Is this the best way to do this.  I would need to be able to search attendees and authors separately in the application.

Thanks very much for the assistance.

[image: Link to table image]

Comment: You appear to have three Staff tables. Does your design require three separate tables, or could you have a single table listing all the staff members?

Comment: Thanks O. Jones,  Good question.... I dont want to duplicate any data of course but wasnt sure how to assign multiple authors and attending engineers to one report without the additional tables.  Natural I want it as efficent as possible but not sure how.  Havent identified examples quite like this in my searches...

Comment: Sounds to me you are trying to implement or going to need to implement SQL table inheritance .. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579079/how-can-you-represent-inheritance-in-a-database .. note the link has sql server tagged but still the rules will work for almost every DBMS..  In PostgreSQL you have a better solution PostgreSQL supports native table inheritance out of the box.

Comment: Thanks Raymond.  I shall invvestigate this option. Cheers Matt

Comment: Yes, you are using a common anti-pattern for a case of inheritance/subtyping. PS Hi. Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use a link/image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text. And never give a diagram without a legend/key. Use edit functions to inline, not links, if you have the rep--make your post self-contained. PS This is a faq you would find answers for if you googled many clear, concise, precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you represent inheritance in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579079/how-can-you-represent-inheritance-in-a-database)

Comment: Thanks for the input Philipxy and positng advice.  I did goodle for several hours, however I an new to mysql and was not sure before what I should have been googling.  Following this question I now have some good avenues to research.  Thanks for the assistance. Matt

Answer (score 0):

You have, I believe, two tables containing entities. The entities are `employee` and `report`.

These entities have two different many-to-many relationships: `author` and `attendee`.

So your tables are these

```
employee                report
--------                -----
employee_id (PK)        report_id (PK)
surname                 title
givenname               releasedate
whatever                whatever
```

Then you have two many:many relationship tables with the same columns as each other. One is `author` and the other is `attendee`.

```
author / attendee
------
employee_id PK, FK to employee.employee_id
report_id   PK, FK to report.report_id
```

Notice the compound (two-column) primary keys.

```
+---------------------+\   /+-------------+\   /+-----------------------+
|                     +-----+   author    +-----+                       |
|                     |/   \+-------------+/   \|                       |
|    employee         |                         |     report            |
|                     |                         |                       |
|                     |\   /+-------------+\   /|                       |
|                     +-----+  attendee   +-----+                       |
+---------------------+/   \+-------------+/   \+-----------------------+


           \   /
           -----    means a many-to-many relationship
           /   \
```

When you determine an employee is an attendee for a certain report, you insert a row into the attendee table with the correct employee and report.

If you want, for example, all authors for each report you can do this sort of thing:

```
  SELECT r.title, r.releasedate, 
         GROUP_CONCAT(e.surname ORDER BY e.surname SEPARATED BY ',')surnames
    FROM report r
    LEFT JOIN author a ON r.report_id = a.report_id
    LEFT JOIN employee e ON a.report_id = e.report_id
   GROUP BY r.title, r.releasedate
   ORDER BY r.releasedate DESC
```

The `LEFT JOIN` operations allow your query to find reports that have no authors. Ordinary inner `JOIN` operations would suppress those rows from your result set.

There is a limitation with this strict E:R design. For many kinds of reports, (scientific papers for example) the order of authors is critically important.  (You want to start an academic food fight? List the authors of a paper in the wrong order.)

So you author table might also contain an ordinal value.

```
author
------
employee_id PK, FK to employee.employee_id
report_id   PK, FK to report.report_id
ordinal     INT
```

and your report query would contain this line.

```
         GROUP_CONCAT(e.surname ORDER BY e.ordinal SEPARATED BY ',')surnames
```

Comment: Thanks very much.  Im knot overly familiar with joins but wondred if the might be appropriate here.  Thanks so much.  I shall digest then implement this.  Thanks O. Jones.  I have repped you but im new here so might not show up.

Comment: Dont forget GROUP_CONCAT has a max length of 1024 chars with the default installation/configuration.. So this might not get the correct results for large tables or GROUPS.

Comment: Thanks Raymond.  Does this max legth refer to concatonated values in a string? or the number of concatoned rows that are searchable or other?